# How can we add field value,say environment, as a variable in web hooks url of JIRA, to invoke a project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have projects in Jenkins, by the names triger-Job-DEV, triger-Job-SYS, etc. I need to invoke these jobs when I get approval in the jira. The jira ticket contains the environment name(DEV, SYS, etc.), and there is seperate jira ticket for each environment. How to use the environment value in jira as variable in web hooks for calling the Jenkins job. I have tried trigger-Job-${Environment} as the job name but it is not invoking the Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Submitting jobs section of the [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

You can do a POST to get a job started. Try this first:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/triger-Job-DEV/build?token=TOKEN
```

If that works, its simply a matter of parameterizing the job name.

NOTE: I noticed that your jira jobs are misspelled as triger-Job-XXX (trigger with 1 g), and you are calling your Jenkins job with the correct spelling of trigger with 2 gs :)

EDIT: From your comment, I understand that DEV, SYS etc is stored as a custom defined variable for each jira task. In that case, this doc has a variable substitution section: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/modules/common/webhook.html

and here they specify that you can use something like {variable.name} to get that value.

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/context-parameters.html

So I assume your URL would look something like :

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/triger-Job-{variable.<your_custom_field_name>}/build?token=TOKEN
```

I have never tried this, so let me know if it works

Comment: I am sorry for my typing mistake. I am able to invoke the job from JIRA end, but the main problem is sending a parameter in job name. I am new to JIRA and REST APIs, Can you please help me in passing a custom defined field value in JIRA, as a parameter to job name in web hooks.